# Is not checking key existence in a static dictionary thread-safe? Resharper thinks it's not

Tags: c#, multithreading, resharper

Resharper suggests wrapping `return dic.Contains("v1");` in a **lock** statement saying "*the field is sometimes used inside synchronized block and sometimes used without synchronization*":

```
public class MyClass
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    protected bool V1Exist()
    {
        return dic.Contains("v1");            
    }
}
```

However I do not see why **lock** is needed in the example. It looks safe-thread to me. Please advise

Comment: `Dictionary` in general is not thread-safe. Use `ConcurrentDictionary` if you need a thread-safe dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries are not thread safe. ConcurrentDictionaries are

Comment: If you write and read dictionary from multiple threads - both writes and reads are not thread safe

Comment: could you describe in more details please what could happen when one thread call dic.Contains("v1")? lets say another thread updating the value, adding or deleting it? What wrong could be? any sort of exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's known that dictionary is not thread-safe, so you should synchronize both writes and reads. But if you want specific example of what can go wrong - consider this small application:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    dict.Add(0, 0);
    new Thread(() => {
        for (int i = 1; i < int.MaxValue; i++) {
            lock (dict) {
                dict.Add(i, i);
                dict.Remove(i);
            }
        }
    }).Start();
    new Thread(() => {
        while (true) {
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(0))
                throw new Exception("cannot happen?");
        }
    }).Start();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

We create dictionary with one entry with key `0`, then we run two threads. First thread constantly adds and removes keys to the dictionary, but note it does NOT remove item with key 0. Item with key 0 is always present.

Second threads constantly checks if there is item with key 0 and throws exception if it does not. You might think that this can never happen, because we never remove item with key 0, but that is not true. If you will run this application it will throw "cannot happen?" exception almost immediately. If you add lock around `ContainsKey` - this will never happen.

So in short, things might go horribly wrong if you are not synchronizing access to not thread safe structures properly, even reads. And you might not even notice that, and will have VERY hard time debugging such issues, because application might behave like all is fine.